# Add Two Numbers Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a question about add two numbers using a linked list from LeetCode.
Below is the question itself,the problem I am facing, and my code.

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
>   integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their
>   nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a
>   linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
>   the number 0 itself.
>
> Example
>
> Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4) Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8 Explanation:
>   342 + 465 = 807.

The problem is that it prints out:

```
Error:
A: 7
B: 7
C: 7
A: 10
B: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Solution.addTwoNumbers(MainClass.java:61)
at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:123)
```

It stops when result.val is 0 and calls NullPointerException. I don't really understand this part because I thought in Java the value 0 was not as same as NullPointerException. Could someone please help me with this? Thank you.

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
    int up = 0;
    ListNode num1 = l1, num2 = l2;

    while (num1 != null || num2 != null){
        int sum = 0;
        int prevUp = 0;

        if (num1 != null && num2 == null){
            sum = num1.val + up;
            if (sum >= 10){
                up = 1;
                sum = sum - 10;
            }
            num1 = num1.next;
            result.val = sum;
            result = result.next;
        }
        else if (num2 != null && num1 == null){
            sum = num2.val + up;
            if (sum >= 10){
                up = 1;
                sum = sum - 10;
            }
            num2 = num2.next;
            result.val = sum;
            result = result.next;
        }
        else{
            sum = num1.val + num2.val;
            System.out.println("A: "+ sum);
            if (sum >= 10){
                prevUp = up;
                up = 1;
                sum = sum - 10;
            }
            System.out.println("B: " + sum);
            num1 = num1.next;
            num2 = num2.next;
            result.val = sum + prevUp;
            System.out.println("C: " + result.val);
            result = result.next;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Reason being you have only one node in result list as you have defined it as ListNode(0). So on next iteration it doesn't have any node.

Answer (score 0):

Reason it's giving **NullPointerException** is you have defined you ResultList with only one node.

Prefer adding new node to it when you find `result.next == null`

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing **Null pointer exception** because of the reason of **result = result.next**, whereas result has one Node only and you have initialized as
 **result = new listNode(0);**

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use reference variable to iterate through the LinkedList

```
ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
ListNode p = result;
```